# Fread/fwrite unexpected behavior

Tags: fwrite, fread

I have created a file 'meta.dat' in my current directory and want the code below to give me this output

> The character B
>
> Number of items read 1

```
 int main() {
  FILE* fp = fopen("meta.dat", "wb");
  char j = 'B';
  fwrite(&j, sizeof(j), 1, fp);
  fclose(fp);
  FILE* fp1 = fopen("meta.dat", "rb");
  char i = '\0';
  int n = fread(&i, sizeof(i), 1, fp1);
  printf("The character %c\n", &i);
  printf("Number of items read %d\n", &n);
}
```

However what I get is this output in my console (I use Windows):

> The character &
>
> Number of items read 6422304

What's wrong with the code? And what's happening behind the scenes, why am I seeing this strange output?

Comment: you are printing the adress of `i` and `n`, not their value. ditch the `&`

Comment: @Andreas oh, thank you :)